# ReadOnly column for CSV

Tags: csv, supercsv

Am using SuperCSV to write my table data into a csv file. Somehow now i need to make the first column of csv not editable (read-only). Couldn't find anything specific. Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, CSV is a pure-text format. You can't lock a part of it - only make the entire file read-only at the file system level.

You need a binary format (Excel, OpenOffice...) where you do get that capability, but with CSV files, it's impossible.

Comment: Thanks, would have to look for alternate solution. Was thinking to write to excel, make the column read-only, write from excel to csv. But this would be quite a overhead for large data.